# Probability that the statement is true

Tags: probability

A speaks truth $3$ times out of $4$ and $B$ $7$ times out of $10$ . they both agree that a white ball has been drawn out from a bag containing $6$ balls of different color . find the probability that the statement is true .

my try .

probability when they say false and agree = $\left(\dfrac56\right)\left(\dfrac14\right)\left(\dfrac3{10}\right)$

probability when they say correct = $\left(\dfrac34\right)\left(\dfrac7{10}\right)\left(\dfrac16\right)$

but from this I am not getting the answer .

the answer gibpven as $\dfrac{35}{36}$

Comment: Is today meaningless marking down questions day?  Because not for the first time today, the question has been marked down, despite there actually being an effort, and no comments as to why it was marked down.

Comment: we don't really know what they actually say if they are lying, so what if they had a tendency to always say 'white ball' if they are lying?  In that case we don't seem to be able to work it out.  So i think the question is incomplete or needs assumptions.  We can't say that 3 time out of 4 that A says 'white ball' that it is a white ball

Comment: @Cato if they say false , then they say that it is white ball .

Comment: In order to answer, we need to know: Given that a white ball is drawn and that A does not speak a truth this round, is A guaranteed to say something other than 'white', or would it be possible for them to say 'white' by random chance?

Comment: @AJMansfield A and B will always say it is white .

Comment: I'm sure 35/36 is too high - if just answering true/false to a proposition that the ball is white - there will be too many false calls on the 5/6 times it is not white

Comment: @hey Ok, so what your saying is, $P(A|W) = 1$, and $P(\neg A|\neg W) = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{5}{6} = \frac{19}{24}$? (Using $P(A)$ to mean 'probability A says "white"' and $P(W)$ to mean probability the ball is white.)

Comment: @hey can you confirm or deny?

Comment: @AJMansfield Now I am getting confused .

Comment: @hey I mean what __exactly__ are the rules. One possibility is this set: (a) a ball is selected at random, (b) A chooses at random whether to speak truth/at random. (c) if A speaks truth, it reports the color of the ball drawn. (d) if A speaks at random, it will independently select a random color to report. --- Some possible modifications to this: (1) If the ball is white, A is guaranteed to speak truth. (2) A choses to speak truth/lies rather than truth/at random, if A choses to speak lies it is guaranteed to report some color other than the one on the ball.

Comment: @AJMansfield which ever ball is drawn , A always speaks it is white ball . He may be speaking truth or lie .

Comment: @hey So, a ball is drawn and you ask A what color the ball is. A says "white", so you mark down whether A got it right or wrong (speaking truth or lie) and then you ask B what color it is. B also says "white", and you mark down whether or not B got it right as well. After asking them about 1000 different balls, A got ~750 of them right, but B only got ~700 of them right, wait what? Something doesn't add up here - is the grader descriminating against B?

Comment: @hey Let's continue this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55439/probability-that-the-statement-is-true).

Comment: @hey - your model answer doesn't seem to follow what you said in these comments, you said that if the ball is white then A (at least) always says it is white and will never lie - they aren't the figures calculated in your answer.  There is a philosophical issue with false statements - a false statement needn't follow rules, unless you are careful to define rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correct Problem

#### Setting

---

There is a bag with six balls in it. Each ball has a different color. One ball is blindly drawn. Two people are being asked which color the ball has after they saw the ball.

Person $A$ tells to truth in $3$ out of $4$ cases. Person $B$ tells the truth in $7$ out of $10$ cases. If one of them doesn't tell to truth the wrong answers are uniformly distributed. Which means nothing else than
$$P(A \text{ says "blue" }|\;A \text{ lies}) = \frac{1}{5} \quad \text{if "blue" isn't the correct answer}$$ 
the same counts for $B$.

#### Question

---

What is the Probability that the drawn ball is white, if person $A$ and person $B$ both are telling that it is white?

#### Solution

---

The actual experiment of drawing a ball doesn't matter any more. Only the distribution of the wrong answers matter.
So we need to calculate the probability
$$P(A \text{ tells the truth } | \; A = B) = \frac{P(A\text{ tells the truth } \cap A=B  )}{P(A=B)}$$
$A = B$ means both give the same answer.

**case 1:**

both are telling the truth: $\frac{3}{4}\frac{7}{10}$

**case 2:**

both are lying the same answer: $\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{10}\frac{1}{5}$

Altogether we receive: $$P(A=B) = \frac{3}{4}\frac{7}{10}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{10}\frac{1}{5} = \frac{108}{200}$$
Now we also know
$$P(A\text{ tells the truth } \cap A=B  ) = P(A \text{ and } B \text{ tell the truth}) = \frac{3}{4}\frac{7}{10} = \frac{21}{40}$$
The last step is building the quotient.

$$\frac{\frac{21}{40}}{\frac{108}{200}} = \frac{35}{36}$$

Answer (score 2):

Ans: $\dfrac{35}{36}$

From the problem, 
P(A speaking truth) $=\dfrac{3}{4}$
P(A not speaking truth) $=1-\dfrac{3}{4}=\dfrac{1}{4}$
P(B speaking truth) $=\dfrac{7}{10}$
P(B not speaking truth) $=1-\dfrac{7}{10}=\dfrac{3}{10}$
P(drawing a white ball) $=\dfrac{1}{6}$
P(drawing a non-white ball) =$\dfrac{5}{6}$

Let $X$ be the event that a white ball is drawn and both assert that it is white(in this event, both speak truth).
$P(X)=\dfrac{1}{6}×\dfrac{3}{4}×\dfrac{7}{10}=\dfrac{7}{80}$

Let $Y$ be the event that a non-white ball is drawn and both assert that it is white (in this event, both lie and say it is white).

Finding probability for this event is tricky. To explain this better, assume that the colors of the balls are red, green, blue, black, yellow and white.

Suppose a red ball is taken.  Then there is a probability of $\dfrac{1}{4}$ that A lie and say it is green or blue or black or yellow or white. Therefore, for A to say, it is a white ball, probability $=\dfrac{1}{4}×\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{1}{20}$

i.e., if a non-white ball is taken, probability that A say it is white 
$=\dfrac{1}{4}×\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{1}{20}$

Similarly, if a non-white ball is taken, probability that B say it is white 
$=\dfrac{3}{10}×\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{3}{50}$

Coming back to the event $Y$ where a non-white ball is drawn and both assert that it is white.
$P(Y)=\dfrac{5}{6}×\dfrac{1}{20}×\dfrac{3}{50}=\dfrac{1}{400}$

$X$ and $Y$ covers all the cases where A and B assert that the ball drawn is white. Note that assertion is true for event $X$ and false for event $Y$

Hence, required probability
$=\dfrac{\dfrac{7}{80}}{\dfrac{7}{80}+\dfrac{1}{400}}=\dfrac{35}{35+1}=\dfrac{35}{36}$

Comment: You definitely have to explain the rules of the game better!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55439/probability-that-the-statement-is-true

Comment: I don't really see your point here, you explained the lying scenario poorly.  We don't actually know what question they were asked, my best guess was they were asked 'is the ball white' and they answered true or false.  There isn't any reason to say that randomising between other balls would occur (they could just as well give Henry VIII as an incorrect answer!)  In any case I asked for clarification on that issue

Answer (score 0):

if a ball is drawn and they are asked if it is white true/false and they both say true - then

P(White | say true) = P(white and say it's true) / P(say true) = 
(1/6)(7/10)(3/4) / ((1/6)(7/10)(3/4) + (5/6)(3/10)(1/4))

= (7/80) (7/80 + 1 / 16) = 7 / 12

one in 16 times  - it isn't white, but they lie and say true to the statement it isn't white.  7 in 80 times it is white and they untruthfully agree it is white.  Therefore it seems impossible that the answer is 35/36 - that's why I over-thought it a bit in the comments

Comment: check my answer